# Sending ajax variable to php variable in the same page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm using ajax to get an json array, when got the array in the ajax function, I need to assign it to php variable in the same page, I tried to use ajax to send the array another time and requested the same page I'm in, and get it the sent data using php, but it would'nt work. this is my code I'm using.

```
function listPages()
{
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $.post("pageFunctions.php",function(data){
    var information=JSON.parse(data);
    //var i=0;
    //var body=document.getElementById('body');
    $.ajax ({
      type:"POST",
      url: "main.php",
      data: { 'value' : information},
      success: function( result ) {

      }
    });
  });
});
}
```

The page I'm in is main.php, first I get the json array from pageFuctions.php, and then try to call main.php to assign the data to php variable by using the following php code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['value']))
{ 
  echo $_POST['value'] ;
}
?>
```

Comment: Why do you have both $_GET and $_POST?

Comment: -1 found over 300 results with 'Sending ajax variable to php variable in the same page' on SO

Comment: I'm sorry, but what is SO? I searched the internet about this issue, and none of the results I found worked.

Comment: SO means Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0):

Since the AJAX uses the `POST` method, there is no `$_GET['value']`. It should be:

```
if (isset($_POST['value'])) {
    echo $_POST['value'];
}
```

Comment: I corrected it, and still won't work!
I tried to echo anything inside the if(isset()) block, and the code does not reach there.

Comment: Your question says you assign the data to a PHP variable. You're not assigning anything, you're just echoing it. So it will become he value of `result` in the jQuery callback.

Comment: The point is I want to use the json array returned by the ajax in php code, and I don't know how to get this done. :(

Answer (score 0):

Use `$_POST['value']` in `if` condition because you use `post` method in ajax.

you can redirect to `main.php` from `pageFunctions.php` file so you can avoid the extra ajax function and client side loading time.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but the problem is not with the extra ajax function, I spend all the day on sending the ajax variable to php variable, and still couldn't find a solution.

Comment: of course, I checked it in the ajax code, and it is not empty.

Comment: remove the single quotes in value just use this code `data: { value : information }` and use `$_REQUEST` instead of `$_POST`. I'm not sure this will work or not